# Scala how to decrease execution time

Tags: scala

I have one method which generate [UUID](http://www.dcalabresi.com/blog/java/generate-java-uuid-performance/) and code as below :

```
def generate(number : Int): List[String] = {
List.fill(number)(Generators.randomBasedGenerator().generate().toString.replaceAll("-",""))
}
```

and I called this as below :

```
for(i <-0 to 100) {
  val a = generate(1000000)
  println(a)
}
```

But for running the above `for` loop it take almost 8-9 minutes for execution,  is there any other way to minimised execution time ?

**Note:** Here for understanding I added `for` loop but in real situation the `generate` method will call thousand of times from other request at same time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Is your loop just a way to help measure the performance?

Comment: I tried using `Actor` modal like this `def receive = {
    case number:Int => List.fill(number)(Generators.randomBasedGenerator().generate().toString.replaceAll("-",""))
  }` but I want that generator list back I'm not sure the `Actor` will solve my issue .

Comment: @Tyler in my application 100 or 1000 of request to call `generate` method for creating `UUID`

Comment: @Yogesh, did you try to profile? What are the hottest places? You can also try to reduce execution time if you generate UUIDs in parallel and merge after (no sure is it your generator Thread-safe)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan can you share link for `profile` ? In my question I added link for UUID and as per that link it mentioned that `The UUID generator is thread-safe`

Comment: @Yogesh, I've meant tools to profile the performance of application, like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you used not the fastest implementation. You should use that one when you pass Random to the constructor `Generators.randomBasedGenerator(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()))`. I did next things:

- Use Array instead of List (Array is faster)
- Removed string replacing, let's measure pure performance of generation

Dependency: `"com.fasterxml.uuid" % "java-uuid-generator" % "3.1.5"`

Result:

```
Generators.randomBasedGenerator(). Per iteration: 1579.6 ms
Generators.randomBasedGenerator() with passing Random Per iteration: 59.2 ms
```

Code:

```
import java.util.{Random, UUID}
import com.fasterxml.uuid.impl.RandomBasedGenerator
import com.fasterxml.uuid.{Generators, NoArgGenerator}
import org.scalatest.{FunSuiteLike, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.duration.Deadline

class GeneratorTest extends FunSuiteLike
  with Matchers {

  val nTimes = 10

  // Let use Array instead of List - Array is faster!
  // and use pure UUID generators
  def generate(uuidGen: NoArgGenerator, number: Int): Seq[UUID] = {
    Array.fill(number)(uuidGen.generate())
  }

  test("Generators.randomBasedGenerator() without passed Random (secure one)") {
    // Slow generator
    val uuidGen = Generators.randomBasedGenerator()
    // Warm up JVM
    benchGeneration(uuidGen, 3)

    val startTime = Deadline.now
    benchGeneration(uuidGen, nTimes)
    val endTime = Deadline.now
    val perItermTimeMs = (endTime - startTime).toMillis / nTimes.toDouble
    println(s"Generators.randomBasedGenerator(). Per iteration: $perItermTimeMs ms")
  }

  test("Generators.randomBasedGenerator() with passing Random (not secure)") {
    // Fast generator
    val uuidGen = Generators.randomBasedGenerator(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    // Warm up JVM
    benchGeneration(uuidGen, 3)    

    val startTime = Deadline.now
    benchGeneration(uuidGen, nTimes)
    val endTime = Deadline.now
    val perItermTimeMs = (endTime - startTime).toMillis / nTimes.toDouble
    println(s"Generators.randomBasedGenerator() with passing Random Per iteration: $perItermTimeMs ms")
  }

  private def benchGeneration(uuidGen: RandomBasedGenerator, nTimes: Int) = {
    var r: Long = 0
    for (i <- 1 to nTimes) {
      val a = generate(uuidGen, 1000000)
      r += a.length
    }
    println(r)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `List`. Filling a `List` with 1,000,000 generated and processed elements is going to take time (and memory) because every one of those elements has to be materialized.

You can generate an infinite number of processed UUID strings instantly if you don't have to materialize them until they are actually needed.

```
def genUUID :Stream[String] = Stream.continually {
  Generators.randomBasedGenerator().generate().toString.filterNot(_ == '-')
}

val next5 = genUUID.take(5) //only the 1st (head) is materialized
next5.length                //now all 5 are materialized
```

You can use `Stream` or `Iterator` for the infinite collection, whichever you find most conducive (or least annoying) to your work flow.

Comment: Thanks I forgot `Stream` now it take almost less than a minutes to execution time

Comment: @Yogesh, Are you sure that it's right solution? It's fast because you're *not consuming* all generated UUIDs. Try to do like `genUUID.take(1000000).length` and you see it has the same problem with performance.

Comment: Yes @ArtavazdBalayan I missed some number in generator I checked again and it takes time to generate ID's

Comment: Hi tested both solution for @jwvh and @ArtavazdBalayan and it take almost same time for both solution and if I added replace `-` in `UUID` then it also increase execution time.

Comment: @Yogesh, could you provide the code? Have you tried to run my code? I measured just UUD generator (not string replacement). And second version is 26 times faster and takes only! **50 ms**

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan I replaced  `nTimes` to `100` and then tested both codes.

Comment: @Yogesh. Hm. Here is the code which I just have tested https://pastebin.com/W3d24b9D. Here is my output https://pastebin.com/0zN6NrG3. I do not see that it takes the same time(the whole time for 100 repeats): 151180 ms(what you use) vs 5172 ms(what I proposed)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan got it thanks for update I tested and it more efficient than stream in terms of execution time

Answer (score 1):

You could use scala's parallel collections to split the load on multiple cores/threads.

You could also avoid creating a new generator every time:

```
class Generator {
  val gen = Generators.randomBasedGenerator()
  def generate(number : Int): List[String] = {
    List.fill(number)(gen.generate().toString.replaceAll("-",""))
  }
}
```